# How do you reorder a sublist of strings, within a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I have a list that looks like this:

```
d= {{{"A5","I4","A2"}, {"A4","I5","A5"}}, 
    {{"A2","A5","I4"}, {"A5","I5","A4"}}, 
    {{"A2","A5","I4"}, {"A5","I4","A4"}}, 
    {{"A2","A5","I4"}}, 
    {{"A2","A5","I4"}}}
```

How would I take list "d" and reorder the sublists so that they're all in the format of:

```
{"A5","I(number)","A(number)"}
```

The output I'm looking for would be:

```
newd={{{"A5","I4","A2"},{"A5","I5","A4"}},
{{"A5","I4","A2"},{"A5","I5","A4"}},
{{"A5","I4","A2"},{"A5","I4","A4"}},
{{"A5","I4","A2"}},
{{"A5","I4","A2"}}
```

Although some of the sublists in d are already in the correct form, I'm trying to find a generic way to put all of the sublists into that correct form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way:

```
d /. x : {__String} :>
  SortBy[x, StringReplace[#, {"A5" -> 1, "I" ~~ _ -> 2, "A" ~~ _ -> 3}] &];

% === newd
```

> ```
> True
> ```

If you look at the output of [`StringReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html) you will see remaining [`StringExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html) heads, which is less than clean, but because they are all the same they do not affect the sort order.

A variation:

```
d /. x : {__String} :> 
   SortBy[x, Characters@# /. {{"A", "5"} -> 1, {"I", _} -> 2, {"A", _} -> 3} &];

% === newd
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
Map[Sort /* RotateLeft, d, {-2}]
% === newd
```

> ```
> {{{"A5", "I4", "A2"}, {"A5", "I5", "A4"}}, {{"A5", "I4", "A2"}, {"A5",
>     "I5", "A4"}}, {{"A5", "I4", "A2"}, {"A5", "I4", "A4"}}, {{"A5", 
>    "I4", "A2"}}, {{"A5", "I4", "A2"}}}
>
> True
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Map[ReverseSortBy[#, {StringCases["A5"], StringCases[RegularExpression["[I\d]"]]}]&,d,{2}]
```

> {{{A5, I4, A2}, {A5, I5, A4}}, {{A5, I4, A2}, {A5, I5, A4}}, {{A5, I4, A2}, {A5, I4, A4}}, {{A5, I4, A2}}, {{A5, I4, A2}}}

```
%==newd
```

> True

Answer (score 1):

```
list =
  {{{"A5", "I4", "A2"}, {"A4", "I5", "A5"}}, 
   {{"A2", "A5", "I4"}, {"A5", "I5", "A4"}}, 
   {{"A2", "A5", "I4"}, {"A5", "I4", "A4"}}, 
   {{"A2", "A5", "I4"}}, {{"A2", "A5", "I4"}}};
```

Using `ReplaceAll`

```
list /. x : {_} | {_, _} :> RotateLeft @* Sort /@ x
```

{{{"A5", "I4", "A2"}, {"A5", "I5", "A4"}}, {{"A5", "I4", "A2"}, {"A5",
"I5", "A4"}}, {{"A5", "I4", "A2"}, {"A5", "I4", "A4"}}, {{"A5",
"I4", "A2"}}, {{"A5", "I4", "A2"}}}